# Xposed - hook static method - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, static, hook, xposed

I'm trying to hook a static method using Xposed, but it's claiming NoSuchMethodError. I'm trying to hook getContext(). This is the code block:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {
    private static final String TAG = "Application";
    private static Application instance;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return instance;
    }
```

The code in Xposed I'm using is 
`findAndHookMethod("me.kuehle.carreport.Application",lpparam.classLoader, "getContext",new XC_MethodHook() {`

I'm able to hook another public method (not static) within this class, but not a private (not static method) [if anyone knows why that's not working, please let me know!]. Thanks!